# Arc Length Question

Tags: arc-length

I was wondering if anyone can help me figure out a mistake I'm making in this problem: calculate the arc length of $y=x^{1/3}$ over $[3,4]$. I am familiar with the formula and once I square the derivative and put it back into the formula, I attempted u-substituion. But now I am stuck.

Comment: I don't think your function has a nice antiderivative.

Answer (score 2):

You have $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ so that $f'(x)= \dfrac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$. Then the length is
$$\int_a^b \sqrt{1+ \big(f'(x)\big)^2} \; dx= \int_3^4 \sqrt{1+ \left(\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}} \right)^2} \;dx= \int_3^4  \sqrt{1+ \dfrac{1}{9 x^{4/3}}} \;dx $$

This last integral has no 'nice' antiderivative, see  [it here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%20Sqrt(1%2B(1%2F(3x%5E(2%2F3)))%5E2)%20dx). So we need to numerically find this, you can use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%20Sqrt(1%2B(1%2F(3x%5E(2%2F3)))%5E2)%20dx%20from%20x%3D3%20to%20x%3D4)  again here to find
$$\int_3^4  \sqrt{1+ \dfrac{1}{9 x^{4/3}}} \;dx \approx 1.010510879128807\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Arc length is $$\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx$$

The derivative is $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{3x^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$

So arc length is $$\int_{3}^{4}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{3x^{\frac{2}{3}}}\right)^2}dx \approx1.010510879$$

Comment: Your work as displayed is correct but your final answer is not.